# Difference between 'Insidious' and 'Pernicious'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Do the words 'insidious' and 'pernicious' have the same meaning? And can they be used in place of each other?

On some places on the web (eg : http://www.dailywritingtips.com/insidious-vs-invidious/), it says that the two words have different uses, but the oxford dictionary defines them both similarly.

Oxford dictionary links : [insidious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/insidious) and [pernicious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pernicious)

Comment: Dictionaries have limited space to explain all the nuances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll go again with Merriam-Webster 3rd International:

insidious:

1. watching for an opportunity to ensnare:  insidious tempter
2. intended to entrap or trick: insidious plot
3. acting by imperceptible degrees: insidious disease
4. having gradual, cumulative, and often hidden effects;
   insidious pressures of modern life
5. subtle: insidious charm

For synonyms it gives 'sly', but obviously that won't work everywhere, mostly 1, 2, possibly 5.

Pernicious has none of these meanings. It basically means destructive or harmful. in the names of diseases (pernicious malaria, pernicious anemia) it means especially severe forms of the disease.

Answer (score 5):

> **Insidious** suggests a lying in wait or a gradualness of effect or
>   approach and applies especially to devious and carefully masked
>   underhandedness.

- a part of an insidious conspiracy to undermine the world- Edmund Wilson
- an insidious tempter

> **Pernicious** is more often applied to things that harm exceedingly or irrepairably by evil or by **insidious** corrupting.

- a pernicious influence
- pernicious propaganda

(excerpts from MW dictionary of synonyms)

Comment: Can something be called insidiously pernicious ? :)

Answer (score 4):

Good research.  Your first reference does a good job of pointing out the subtle distinctions. In particular, it points out that "insidious" is

- "(... neutral, but the word is rarely used except in a negative sense.)"

The Oxford dictionary does define them *similarly*, but not *identically*:

for "insidious", notice that it mentions both the gradual nature and the harmful effect together.

For "pernicious", it mentions first the harmful effect and then says  "especially" about the gradualness.

So according to Oxford Dictionaries:

- "insidious" things **always come on gradually**  and **always have harmful effects**.
- "pernicious" things are **always** harmful**, and often (but not necessarily) *come on gradually*.

So you could use either word for things that are very hamful **and** come on gradually or subtly.

However, for something that is only, say, *annoying* (like that song you just can't get out of your head) you could say it is "insidious", but not "pernicious". It *insinuates* itself, not *innocently*, but *innocuously*.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So, if something is harmful and shows its effect with a slow, subtle build-up, can I use any of the two words to describe it? Or, is one better than the other?

Comment: It's your choice.  See how you like the way it sounds to say it. For instance, if you're writing a poem, it might depend on whether you need it to rhyme with "hideous" or with "vicious."  But that's writing style, not grammar or usage.

Answer (score 3):

The actual *OED* does not make them synonyms, defining "pernicious" as extremely harmful (from the Latin *per* (intensive prefix) + *nex*, *necis* death) and "insidious" as treacherous (from the Latin *insidere*, to lie in wait).  Ambushers lying in wait for you can't intend anything but harm, but they needn't mean to kill you.  And something can be pernicious and readily apparent.  Consider the sentence from [*The Province of Jurisprudence*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZWZE9QfSpowC&pg=PA186&dq=%22pernicious%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgyahUKEwiYsNSYhN_GAhWIW5IKHYL-DIQ#v=onepage&q=%22pernicious%22&f=false) by John Austin:

> What appears **pernicious** to one person may appear beneficial to
>   another.

That doesn't mean that the two can't go together.  **Pernicious** anemia was named before its cause was understood, at a time when it was invariably fatal.  But it is also an **insidious** disease, developing slowly with multiple symptoms that evade an easy diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

**Insidious** an insidious change or problem spreads gradually without being noticed, and causes serious harm

an insidious trend towards censorship of the press

---

**Pernicious** very harmful or evil, often in a way that you do not notice easily

the pernicious effects of poverty.

Answer (score -2):

Pernicious is just a more severe and harmful form of insidious.  Something that is insidious in nature may or may not be pernicious.   The bermuda grass may be taking over my yard insidiously, but i would not say it is pernicious.  I would save pernicious for some diseases that come on gradually but have severe consequences.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U and thank you for your answer! On this site we strive to produce the best answers to questions and it is important that they are **backed up by relevant information**. Can you find some links to a dictionary, for example?

Comment: Pernicious is bad. Insidious is sneaky bad. The answer misses this distinction.