# a word that means harm or damage is being done to someone without the person realizing

Tags: single-word-requests

for example, if someone was using a medicine that on the outside was helping them but was actually causing long-term harm. I seem to think it begins with the letter V?

Comment: Close, but probably no cigar: [**nostrum**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nostrum) - *a medicine prepared by an unqualified person, especially one that is **not considered effective***.

Comment: 'Insidious' or 'Pernicious'. Perhaps best treated at  [difference between 'insidious' and 'pernicious'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259918/difference-between-insidious-and-pernicious)

Comment: The collocation [***pernicious nostrum***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pernicious+nostrum&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpernicious%20nostrum%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpernicious%20nostrum%3B%2Cc0) apparently had considerable currency a couple of centuries ago.

Comment: The claimed duplicate is _not_ a duplicate as 'pernicious' is non-metaphorical here and a valid answer. But I felt this should be closed; the question I linked to provided answers.

Comment: Hi guys unfortunately none of the suggestions are correct, I have since given up my search for this word! I'm sure it will pop up in a few years when I no longer need it haha